# navigation: sensor is out of bound. so the costmap cannot raytrace for it

Tags: navigation, costmap, costmap-2d, global-costmap, local-costmap

I am trying to do a navigation stack on the pepper robot. when I launch move_base, i have noticed the following error. i have seen a similar kind of issue and I tried that modification but was still not successful like setting static map to true in global costmap and rolling window to true in local costmap.

> [ WARN] [1709061982.723394436]: The origin for the sensor at (0.75, 0.24, 0.00) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.

common_costmap_params.yaml:

```
robot_radius: 0.4  
footprint: [[0.175, -0.175], [0.0897,-0.23 ], [0.009,-0.225], [-0.122,-0.15], [-0.24,0.0], [-0.122,0.15], [0.009,0.225], [0.0897,0.23], [0.175,0.175]]

map_type: voxel

obstacle_layer:
 enabled:              true
 footprint_clearing_enabled: true
 max_obstacle_height:  2.0
 #origin_z:             0.0
 #z_resolution:         0.2
 #z_voxels:             10
 unknown_threshold:    15
 mark_threshold:       0
 combination_method:   1
 track_unknown_space:  false   
 obstacle_range: 2.5
 raytrace_range: 3.0
 origin_z: 0.0
 z_resolution: 1.0 
 z_voxels: 10 #10
 publish_voxel_map: false
 observation_sources: depth_pc scan 

 depth_pc:
   data_type: PointCloud2
   topic:  /pepper_robot/camera/depth/points
   marking: true
   clearing: true
   min_obstacle_height: 0.2 
   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
   observation_persistence: 0.0
   obstacle_range: 0.75 
   raytrace_range: 2.0
   inf_is_valid: false

 scan:
   data_type: LaserScan
   topic: pepper_robot/laser
   marking: true
   clearing: true
   obstacle_range: 2.0  
   inf_is_valid: true
   min_obstacle_height: -0.15 
   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
   observation_persistence: 0.0

inflation_layer:
 enabled:              true
 cost_scaling_factor:  0.5  
 inflation_radius:     0.20  

inflation_layer_local:
 enabled:              true
 cost_scaling_factor:  1.5  
 inflation_radius:     0.20 

static_layer:
 enabled:              true
```

local_costmap:

```
    global_frame: /map
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    update_frequency: 5.0
    publish_frequency: 2.0
    static_map: false
    rolling_window: true
    width: 3.0
    height: 3.0
    resolution: 0.05
    transform_tolerance: 2.0
    plugins: 
        - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
        - { name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer" }
```

global_costmap:

```
    global_frame: /map
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    #update_frequency: 5.0
    #static_map: true
    update_frequency: 2.0
    publish_frequency: 2.5
    static_map: true 
    transform_tolerance: 2.0
    always_send_full_costmap: true
    plugins:
        - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
        - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
        - {name: obstacle_layer,          type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
```